# Watchkit: playHaptic has no effect when executing in an inactive or background application state

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I want to play the notification in iWatch in both state background and foreground.

I tried this but this is not working only in the background

```
DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
     WKInterfaceDevice().play(.notification)
}
```

Error

> WKInterfaceDevice playHaptic has no effect when executing in an
>   inactive or background

Also, I read this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52630.

Now the question is this, Is there any way to vibrate the watch in the background and foreground for reminding purpose? 
or any other alternate way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1628128-play) clearly states that this is not possible.

> This method has no effect when called while your shared 
>   WKExtension object's applicationState property is either background or inactive.

Only workout apps can play Haptic feedback in the background if an active Workout session is running.

If you need don't want to play a Haptic, but only need the vibration, you can send a local notification to the user, which will either play a sound or vibration depending on whether Silent mode is on or off.

Comment: We don't want to send notification because of its irritating to reminding in every 1 minute.

Comment: As I have already stated, there is no way to play a Haptic when your app is in the background. You can use a notification to achieve this, but there's no other workaround at the moment.